# What does the "must export "data." " Error Mean? Discord.Js, Vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js and am getting an error in the terminal that says

```
throw new Error(`File ${commandFilePath} must export "data".`);
      ^

Error: File C:\Users\joeh4\OneDrive\Desktop\PIEA ScrimBot\commands\ban.js must export "data"."
```

here is my code:

```js
const {
  Client,
  Interaction,
  ApplicationCommandOptionType,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  /**
   *
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Interaction} interaction
   */

  callback: async (client, interaction) => {
    const targetUserId = interaction.options.get('target-user').value;
    const reason = interaction.options.get('reason').value;

    await interaction.deferReply();

    const targetUser = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(targetUserId);

    if (!targetUser) {
      await interaction.editReply('That User is not in PIEA Scrims');
      return;
    }

    if (targetUser.id === interaction.guild.ownerId) {
      await interaction.editReply(
        " You can't ban that user because they destroyed you in a scrim",
      );
      return;
    }

    const targetUserRolePosition = targetUser.roles.highest.position;
    const requestUserRolePosition = interaction.member.roles.highest.position;
    const botRolePosition = interaction.guild.members.me.roles.highest.position;

    if (targetUserRolePosition >= requestUserRolePosition) {
      await interaction.editReply(
        'You cant ban that user because they are better than you',
      );
      return;
    }

    if (targetUserRolePosition >= botRolePosition) {
      await interaction.editReply(
        'I cant ban them because they won against me in a scrim',
      );
      return;
    }

    try {
      await targetUser.ban({ reason });
      await interaction.editReply(`${targetUser} was Banned!\nFor ${reason}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`There Was An Error Banning this user: ${error}`);
    }
  },

  name: 'ban',
  description: 'Bans a member from PIEA Scrims',
  options: [
    {
      name: 'target-user',
      description: 'The user you want to ban',
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Mentionable,
      required: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'reason',
      description: 'The reason you want to ban the user',
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  permissionsRequired: [PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers],
  botPermissions: [PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers],
};
```

I have already tried searching for this problem and checking for "data" in my file, I also Already tried adding a data property

Comment: It's not a discord.js error and we don't know your code but I think you should have a `data` property exported from every command file. Well, that's clearly not present in this one.